# Why is the lightning waveform modelled by double exponential waveform?

Tags: charge, capacitance, atmospheric-science, dielectric, lightning

As per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning): The electric current within a typical negative CG lightning discharge rises very quickly to its peak value in 1–10 microseconds, then decays more slowly over 50–200 microseconds.
[image]

1. **Why does the lightning cause a fast rise and slow decay?** What is the physics behind that?
   Isn't  it like the [discharge of a charged capacitor](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu%2Fhbase%2Felectric%2Fcapdis.html&psig=AOvVaw0UPmQ7vYfjqccw9AwqLMKs&ust=1670386518008000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCJDureqQ5PsCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ) (~cloud) through a resistance (atmosphere) - Current is high in the beginning and gradually tapers down.

[image]

[image]

2. Is double exponential a realistic case of exponential decay, where the current cannot rise to high value instantaneously (as in an exponential decay)?

But exponential current decay circuits are quite realistic in electrical engineering.

3. With respect to lightning, most of the sources denote the current waveform , but some [sources](http://vlabs.iitkgp.ac.in/vhvlab/html/pages/ivg/theory.html) denote  the voltage as double exponential function. Is it correct to represent voltage as double expoential?

Answer (score 2):

The initial fast rise occurs because of an *avalanche process* in which the more current that flows, the lower the resistance becomes to that current flow: it is a positive feedback mechanism feeding upon energy that was stored up in advance of the breakdown event.

The slower decay is because the recombination events which restore the ionized air to its nonconductive state require time to go to completion; the characteristic time scale for recombination happens to be longer than that of the breakdown avalanche.